# Is it legal to show kids reaching orgasm with clothes on?

Tags: legal, nymphomaniac

In *Nymphomaniac: Vol. I (2013)*, a little girl is shown having an orgasm while flying in the sky with clothes on. The narration says that the girl is having an orgasm.

In *Babel*, a kid is shown masturbating to his sister bathing (masturbation not shown).

I already viewed this [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53479/how-is-return-to-the-blue-lagoon-legal-if-milla-jovovich-was-15-when-it-was-shot), which is about toplessness, but I am referring to orgasms, which are inherently sexual.

Is it legal to show kids reaching orgasm with clothes on?

Comment: This will depend on the jurisdiction of where the film is being shown. Clearly unless the scene is patently *obscene* it will be legal.

Comment: Different countries will have different laws, but since the orgasm isn't real and just a role to play in acting, it would be OK.  In the movie The Good Son, McCauley Culkin (who was just a child at the time) committed a murder, and that was OK with audiences.

Comment: @JohnnyBones It will still depend on the locale where the movie is airing.  American sensibilities can (in some parts of the country) be remarkably accepting of violence, but abhorrent to the mere suggestion of sexuality.

Comment: This is more of a question for https://law.stackexchange.com. But I would advise against migrating it until the author clarified which jurisdiction they are talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the US, at least, the law is reasonably clear.  Child pornography, which is unlawful, is defined as

> any visual depiction of sexually explicit conduct involving a minor

Sexually explicit conduct is in turn defined as

> sexual intercourse, including genital-genital, oral-genital, anal-genital, or oral-anal, whether between persons of the same or opposite sex as well as bestiality, *masturbation*, sadistic or masochistic abuse, and the lascivious exhibition of the genitals or pubic area of any person.

But the action has to actually be *shown*.  A boy looking down, moving his arm rhythmically, would not count.

Separately, a work could be be prosecuted as *obscene* if

> the average person, applying contemporary community standards would find that the work, taken as a whole, appeals to the prurient interest; the work depicts or describes, in a patently offensive way, sexual conduct specifically defined by the applicable state law; and the work, taken as a whole, lacks serious literary, artistic, political, or scientific value.